# Jenkins: How to share (database) resources between builds?

Tags: jenkins

I have plenty of build jobs that require a database connection with exclusive  access to the database. I.e. while one of these jobs is running, no other job may access the same database.
I could use the [Lockable Resources Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin) to synchronize over ***one*** database resource but in order to allow parallel builds, I have four data sources that I can use for my builds.

Is there any way to achieve some kind of resource pooling for the Jenkins jobs, where each job takes one of the availabe data source resources?

Or is it possible that every executor has its own build settings so that I can associate a different data source to every build executor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't worked with Lockable Resources Plugin, but with this one:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/External+Resource+Dispatcher

In that plugin you are able to lock it based on something. You can say: give me a resource with a specific attribute (name == blabla) and then lock it. Can't you do the same with label in Lockable Resources Plugin? You define 4 different resources with the same label? So when you request it, you get one of the four?